# Referencing my own .tex-files

Tags: cross-referencing, ref, xr

I am trying to reference doc1.tex in doc2.tex inside the same project on overleaf. I have seen several posts here, but they were all not detailed enough for me. I am very new to LateX. So far I have understood that I should use the xr-package somehow. But when I try to implement the package using Overleafs own guide it doesn't work. Can anyone help me with what I should write in my two document for the referencing to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have not given many clues here. Normally a project on overleaf only has one main document with `\documentclass` and other tex files are `\input` in to it. In such a case you don't need `xr` just use `\label` and `\ref` as if it were one file.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want the content in doc1.tex to be included in doc2.tex. I just want to reference doc1.tex in doc2.tex.

Comment: overleaf needs some special settings due to the way they process files. There is a description here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf. If you have problems with it, ask the overleaf support for help.